# Is there a way to avoid repeating of key-value mappings in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary which maps particular hour (fetched from the dates) to a particular number.

```
time_of_day_mapping = {
    4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0,
    12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1,
    17: 2, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 2, 21: 2, 22: 2, 23: 2,
    0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3}
```

It frustrates me that some of the values are mapped on the same values such as 0, 1, 2 and 3 are mapped to 3. I thought of changing the dictionary keys format to range or tuples somehow to avoid repeating in such a way:

```
time_of_day_mapping = {
    range(4, 12): 0,
    range(12, 17): 1,
    range(17, 24): 2,
    range(0, 4): 3}
```

But then I am not sure how to get the mapping efficiently with ranges as keys if I have only one value for that like this:

```
df['some_date'].apply(lambda x: time_of_day_mapping.get(x.hour)
```

I would be glad to get some advice. Or maybe in terms of efficiency, it's better not to change anything about dictionary format?

Comment: Unless you're dealing with millions of elements, don't worry about the extra memory.

Comment: what is the problem with them being mapped to the same number?

Comment: In a dictionary the keys ARE unique , however the values may NOT be unique.

Comment: @Banana it doesn't seem to be such a big problem, I was just wondering whether there is a possibility to handle this to avoid repeating so it would look better.

Comment: @KonstantinosKatsantonis I'm aware of it.

Comment: So your concerns are only about the code readability, right? Not the actually created dictionary.

Comment: you could use tuples as keys but indeed the lookup will be less efficient. I would just leave it as it is

Comment: How about using comprehensions (if it's a code readability issue) like:  {hour: (3 if hour <= 3 else 0 if hour <= 11 else 1 if hour <= 16 else 2) for hour in range(24)}

Comment: BTW: If you need the time_of_day mapping to manipulate a `pandas.DataFrame`, why not store the mapping in a dataframe as well and then join on those dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your biggest concern is code readability, you can define your dict like you did, but then "unpack" it to the original form (so you can do a regular dictionary lookup):

```py
time_of_day_mapping = {
    range(4, 12): 0,
    range(12, 17): 1,
    range(17, 24): 2,
    range(0, 4): 3
}

time_of_day_mapping = dict((key, value) for range_obj, value in time_of_day_mapping.items() for key in list(range_obj))

print(time_of_day_mapping)
```

after running this code, `time_of_day_mapping` is exactly the dict as it first appears in your question.

and let me suggest, for increased readability, you use **inclusive** start-end tuples as keys, and then `range` them in the comprehension, like this:

```py
time_of_day_mapping = {
    (4, 11): 0,
    (12, 16): 1,
    (17, 23): 2,
    (0, 3): 3
}

time_of_day_mapping = dict((key, value) for (start, end), value in time_of_day_mapping.items() for key in list(range(start, end+1)))

print(time_of_day_mapping)
```

I think it's nicer to see `(4,11):0` and not `(4,12):0` when `d[12] != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are either looking for a bidirectional map, or for a mapping of keys to collections.

The former can be achieved using a [bidict](https://pypi.org/project/bidict/0.11.0/).

```py
from bidict import bidict                                                                                                                                                                     

d = bidict([('a', 23), ('b', 42)])                                                                                                                                                            

d.inverse[23] # 'a'
```

The latter can be achieved with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples).

```py
from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                                                                           

d = defaultdict(list)
d['a'].append(23)                                                                                                                                                                             
d['a'].append(42)                                                                                                                                                                             
d['a'] # [23, 42]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a list of comprehension you could do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

time_of_day_mapping = {range(4, 12): 0, range(12, 17): 1, range(17, 24): 2, range(0, 4): 3}

df = pd.DataFrame([datetime(2019,6,25,4,0,0), datetime(2019,6,25,12,0,0), datetime(2019,6,25,17,0,0), datetime(2019,6,25,2,0,0)], columns = ["some_date"])
df['my_new_col'] = df['some_date'].apply(lambda x: [time_of_day_mapping[key] for key in time_of_day_mapping if x.hour in key][0])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------+------------+
|    |      some_date       | my_new_col |
+----+----------------------+------------+
| 0  | 2019-06-25 04:00:00  |          0 |
| 1  | 2019-06-25 12:00:00  |          1 |
| 2  | 2019-06-25 17:00:00  |          2 |
| 3  | 2019-06-25 02:00:00  |          3 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `tuple` instead of range and simply search for an hour value in your `dict`

like this:

```
from random import randint
import datetime

#use tuple instead of range
time_of_day_mapping = {
    (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11): 0,
    (12, 13, 14, 15, 16): 1,
    (17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23): 2,
    (0, 1, 2, 3): 3}

# here I created a list of random datetimes
dates = []
for i in range(0,10):
    date=datetime.datetime(randint(2005,2025), randint(1,12),randint(1,28),randint(1,23),randint(0,59))
    dates.append(date.hour)
print(dates)

res = [time_of_day_mapping[k] for d in dates for k in time_of_day_mapping if d in k]
print(res)
```